# Re-order columns values based on values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like know, how can we re-order the columns in  descending order, while retrieving the data.

Please try to provide a solution, which can be generic for any number of columns.

Every row should be re-arranged in descending order, while we are retrieving the data. I am trying to do something like order by, but not based on column, but row. Is it achievable.

Comment: I am sorry but the data is confidential so i can't display it here.

Comment: You don't have to display the data you're working with. Something similar to it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When ordering try using the 'NULLS LAST' option, e.g.:

```
select * from your_table 
  order by col1 desc nulls last,
           col2 desc nulls last,
           col3 desc nulls last,
           col4 desc nulls last;
```

If that does not help, please, provide sample data and the result data you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Well depends on what result you want. If you want data sorted by the first filled column then this should do it.

```
select nvl(col1,nvl(col2,nvl(col3,col4))), 'rest of data'
from testing
order by nvl(col1,nvl(col2,nvl(col3,col4))) desc nulls last;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ordering to be done by using w as descending. if it is null then use the x. if its null then use the y if it is null then use the z

This would be `COALESCE`:

```
order by coalesce(w,x,y,z) desc
```

This gets you a result like the following. First all the rows that start with the highest value (8 in my example), then all those that start with the next value (7 in my example).

```
+ --+---+---+---+
| w | x | y | z |
+ --+---+---+---+
| 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 |
|   |   | 8 | 0 |
|   | 8 | 6 | 8 |
| 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
|   |   | 7 | 0 |
|   | 7 | 8 | 9 |
+ --+---+---+---+
```

If you want to further order within these rows, then extend the `ORDER BY` clause, e.g.:

```
order by coalesce(w,x,y,z) desc, coalesce(x,y,z) desc, coalesce(y,z) desc, z desc
```

Comment: i get an error that  expected DATE got NUMBER. w,x,y are date and z is number. how to change it? I am just a beginner so kindly help!

Comment: @user11118440: This cannot work. If I get one row with w = 2019-01-01 and another row with w null, x null, y null, and z = 25, then how to sort the two rows? What comes first, the 25 or the 2019-01-01? You seem to want something else. Add sample data and expected result to your request, so we see how you want your rows ordered.